# MemgraphDB: Using openCypher to add names to Karate club friendship network

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb, opencypher

I'm using Karate club friendship network sample data set to learn Cypher. Here is the description of it:

The model consists of 34 users where some users are friends within a university karate club.

- `User` node - A user in the karate club.

  - `id` - A unique identified for a user (e.g. "1").
  - `name` - Name of the user which is equal to the id (e.g. "1").
    Relationships:
- `FRIENDS_WITH` relationship - Connects a `User` to another `User` friend.

The description says, and my query confirms that users have no names, they have ID and name the same.

[image]

I'd like to change this. How can I update the names of all nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
UNWIND [['0','Adam'],['1','Bridget'],['2','Charlie'],...,['33','Zoe']] AS data
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE u.id = data[0]
SET u.name = data[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple task, but the query is a little bit longer. The image shows that there are 34 nodes. This block needs to be ajusted and repeated 34 times:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '0'
SET n.name = 'Zoe';
```

So the query for all 34 names could be:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '0'
SET n.name = 'Zoe';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '1'
SET n.name = 'Isla';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '2'
SET n.name = 'Ella';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '3'
SET n.name = 'Violet';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '4'
SET n.name = 'Grace';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '5'
SET n.name = 'Hannah';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '6'
SET n.name = 'Lily';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '7'
SET n.name = 'Madison';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '8'
SET n.name = 'Evelyn';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '9'
SET n.name = 'Penelope';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '10'
SET n.name = 'Leo';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '11'
SET n.name = 'Adam';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '12'
SET n.name = 'Dylan';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '13'
SET n.name = 'Max';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '14'
SET n.name = 'Aaron';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '15'
SET n.name = 'Eli';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '16'
SET n.name = 'Oscar';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '17'
SET n.name = 'Christopher';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '18'
SET n.name = 'Miles';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '19'
SET n.name = 'Nolan';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '20'
SET n.name = 'Andrew';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '21'
SET n.name = 'Joshua';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '22'
SET n.name = 'Isaac';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '23'
SET n.name = 'James';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '24'
SET n.name = 'Elijah';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '25'
SET n.name = 'Ian';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '26'
SET n.name = 'Gavin';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '27'
SET n.name = 'Adrian';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '28'
SET n.name = 'Robert';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '29'
SET n.name = 'Theo';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '30'
SET n.name = 'Eric';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '31'
SET n.name = 'Michael';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '32'
SET n.name = 'Logan';
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.id = '33'
SET n.name = 'Tyler';
```